# Laravel Validation on localhost or url

Tags: php, database, validation, laravel

Currently I am trying to use active_url to validate a url field in my database setup. However, I want to allow users to enter in "localhost" as well. This fails the rules for active_url. How do I setup a rule for validation on a text field that passes active_url or matches "localhost"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a simple solution would be to short circuit the validator using conditional logic.

Example:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$rules = array(
    'url' => 'active_url' // check DNS if valid (your default option)
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($host !== 'localhost' && $validator->fails()) { // this is where the magic happens
   // do stuff on failure

}
```

If you're running on localhost, it's just going to short-circuit the condition and it will return false.